# problem running "mvn site"

Tags: java, maven-2

When I try to run "mvn site" lifecycle, I get the following error

```
WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:2.0.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.084s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 23 18:36:17 IST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0.1:site (default-site) on project store-service-impl: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0.1:site failed: Unable to load the mojo 'site' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0.1'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/doxia/module/xhtml/decoration/render/RenderingContext
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/don/workspace/WTP_REPOSITORYQA_DM/WTP/Repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/2.0.1/maven-site-plugin-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/don/workspace/WTP_REPOSITORYQA_DM/WTP/Repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 4
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
[ERROR] import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
```

I tried using the 3.0-beta-3 version of the site plugin instead, but I get similar results. I've no idea where to start with this, so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: which version of maven are you using? The site generation was changed drastically between maven 2 and 3. And could you add the bit of the pom related to the site plugin? And just in case, could you delete all the plugins from your local repo? Maven is complaining that the pom is invalid, which sometimes happens when it's not downloaded properly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're hitting a bug in doxia 1.0, you're using a pretty old version of the maven site plugin that has a dependency on this defective version of doxia.

Try specifying the version for the maven-site-plugin as 2.3.